# How do I specify a delegate's return type without upcasting?

Tags: .net, casting, expression-trees, upcasting

I have this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can create this concrete method with a return type of object and return the integer Id without upcasting:

```
object ConcreteGetId(MyClass mc)
{
    return mc.Id;
}
```

However, when I try to generate a delegate using expressions...

```
static Delegate GenerateGetId()
{
    Type MyType = typeof(MyClass);

    ParameterExpression EntityParameter = Expression.Parameter(MyType);
    MemberExpression Property = Expression.Property(EntityParameter, MyType.GetProperty("Id"));
    LambdaExpression Lambda = Expression.Lambda(Property, EntityParameter);

    Delegate d = Lambda.Compile();

    return d;
}
```

...the return type is always integer:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[MyNamespace.MyClass,System.Int32]>(MyNamespace.MyClass $var1)
{
    $var1.Id
}
```

I want it to compile to `Func<MyClass, object>`, but the only way I know how to do this is to upcast Id to object like this:

```
LambdaExpression Lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.TypeAs(Property, typeof(object)), EntityParameter);
```

That compiles to this:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[MyNamespace.MyClass,System.Object]>(MyNamespace.MyClass $var1)
{
    $var1.Id .As System.Object
}
```

I've been reading that there are slight performance hits to casting, so I'd rather not cast at all.  Plus, there's no point in upcasting since an object is always every type in the hierarchy above it.

And perhaps this isn't even a problem at all, that it's not *really* casting, that it just appears it is when looking at the expression's debug info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it without a cast. In your `ConcreteGetId` method, there *is* a cast to `object`, it's just not explicit.

Comment: So then is it safe to say that doing an explicit cast within my generated delegate is of marginal to no detriment to performance?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, no. Boxing a value type into an object always impacts performance negatively, but that's not the point, because in this case you can't avoid it (if you want the delegate to return `object`).

Comment: The thing is, if I'm not mistaken, your ConcreteGetId is also doing a cast, just not explicitly. There is no performance difference between the ConcreteGetId method, and your compiled delegate with cast. I guess on IL level you would see the same code. Please correct me anyone if I'm wrong!!!